# Animating an Image with ImageView

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-imageview

I'm pretty new to Android programming, and I've looked around but haven't been able to find a clear-cut answer. I need to slowly animate an image by switching it with anothe, like a sprite. If anyone can help, it seems like it should be really simple. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean frame by frame animation? Or switching between two entirely different images?

Comment: Technically, two different images. But does it matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a TransitionDrawable
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html

```
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = //your first drawable
layers[1] = //your second drawable
TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable(layers);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(transition);
transition.startTransition(1500);
```